# variable value not getting displayed on laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have following in my laravel blade file.

```
@slot('title') {{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }} @endslot
        <?php if (App\Models\DepartmentUser::where('user_id',  $user->id)->exists()) {
            $jobTitleId=App\Models\DepartmentUser::where('user_id',  $user->id)->first()->job_title_id;
            if($jobTitleId){
                $jobTitle=App\JobTitle::where('id',$jobTitleId)->first()->title;
                echo '@slot'.$jobTitle.'@endslot';
            }
         }
         else{
                echo 'No job title set.';
            }
        ?>
```

Here, I'm trying to echo, user's job title if they are assigned to any department, and if they are not assigned to any then, No job title set text has to be shown..

But When I run this, it won't display me the job title.

I tried `dd` the `$jobTitle` it was printing the output...

Comment: Can you try with some hardcoded vale like ```echo 'Test Department'``` just to check echo statement is working fine or not. I'm not sure but lil doubtful

Comment: Why are you not using blade syntax/commands inside blade? Is `echo '@slot'.$jobTitle.'@endslot';` where the jobtitle is supposed to output? Have you tried removing `@slot` and `@endslot` from it?

Comment: @SurajSanwal yes it was not even printing

Comment: @brombeer I tried both ways, nothing seems to be working...

Comment: Can you please mind showing the output with dd() method

Comment: @SurajSanwal "Driver"

Comment: The "ideal" way would be to move the logic part to your controller and pass the `$jobTitle` to your blade view, then display it. Your `echo '@slot'.$jobTitle.'@endslot';` will _not_ be parsed as blade. Place `@slot` and `@endslot` around your logic

Comment: you should put all your bussiness logic to controller/models and then pass data from controller to view.